# Average Response time Increasing at Stress testing

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter, amazon-rds

I am using CodeIgniter for my API implementation. Please find the server resources and technologies used as follows :

**SUMMARY**

```
Framework : CodeIgniter

Database : MySQL (Hosted on RDS) (1 MASTER & 2 SLAVE)

Hosting :  AWS t2.Micro

Web Server  : Nginx
```

Following is the Report of the LOADER.IO report as per my test.

My API MIN RESPONSE TIME :  383 MS

NUMBER OF HITS : 10000 / 1 MIN CONCURRENT

As you can see in below image AVERAGE RESPONSE is 6436 MS .

I am expecting at least 100000 / 1 MIN users for watching an event on my application.

I would appreciate if anybody can help with some OPTIMIZATIONS Suggestions.

[image]

**MAJOR THINGS I have done so far**

1) SWITCHED TO NGINX FROM APACHE

2) MASTER / SLAVE Configuration (1 MASTER , 2 SLAVE)

3) CHECKED each INDEX in USER JOURNEY in the application

4) CODE OPTIMIZATION :  AS you can see 383 MS is a good Response time of an API
5) USED EXPLAIN of MYSQL for checking the explaination of Queries

Comment: you forgot  **query optimization**

Comment: the question is why 100000 concurrent connections?

Comment: Blindly messing with MySQL seems wasteful. You need to identify the bottleneck and start from there.

Comment: do https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/benchmark.html and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html as well

Comment: @IvascuMadalin : I mean , I am expecting that much traffic.

Comment: It might be useful to install some caching method, like Redis or Memcached under your stack if you query static data at api calls, or the api call does inserts. You can store the "soon to be" inserted data in Memcached and a cron job can do your inserts. It makes the app run faster, because queries can be slow, at least slower, than accessing a variable from memory and a slow query can hang your server up. On frequent api usage, one of the above caching methods are recommended.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` if it mostly involves a single type of query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to focus to tune your mysql to get faster queries execution and thus you can save time. 
To to this, I would suggest to do the following:

You can setup them in /etc/my.cnf (Red Hat) or /etc/mysql/my.cnf (Debian) file:

```
# vi /etc/my.cnf
```

And then append following directives:

```
query_cache_size = 268435456
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=1048576
```

In above example the maximum size of individual query results that can be cached set to 1048576 using query_cache_limit system variable. Memory size in Kb.

These changes will make your queries to give faster results by caching frequently executing queries result and it also updates its cached result when any rows will get updated. This will be done by mysql engine and this is how you can save time.

**ONE MORE SUGGESTION:**
    As you are using `t2.micro` you would get 1Gig of RAM and 1 CPU. So I would suggest to go with `t2.medium` which will give you 4.0 GiB RAM and 2 CPU.

Comment: thank you ...can we access my.cnf file on RDS ? if this is possible then plz let me know how i can we access it???

Comment: @VikasSharma, you need to google for that. I can point out a way. Check the [link here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130170/how-to-change-query-cache-type-to-2-in-aws-rds) Or Check [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.Modifying)

Answer (score 1):

For 1667 `SELECTs` per second, you *may* need to have multiple Slaves.  With such, you can scale arbitrarily far.

However, it may be that the `SELECTs` can be made efficient enough to not need the extra Slaves.  Let's see the queries.  Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

It is possible to run thousands of *simple* queries per second.

"100000 / 1 MIN" -- Is that 100K *connections*?  Or 100K *queries* from a smaller number of *connections*?  There is a big difference -- establishing a connection is more costly than performing a simple query.  Also, having 100K *simultaneous* connections is more than I have every heard of.  (And I have seen thousands of servers.  I have seen 10K connections (high-water-mark) and 3K "Threads_connected" -- both were in deep do-do for various reasons.  I have almost never seen more than 200 "Threads_running" -- that is actual queries being performed simultaneously; that is too many for stability.)

Ouch -- With the `query_cache_size` at 256MB on 1GB of RAM, you don't have room for anything else!  That is a *tiny* server.  Even on a larger server do *not* set that tunable to more than 50M.  Otherwise the "pruning" slows things down more than the QC speeds them up!

And, how big are the tables in question?

And, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`

And, what version are you running?  Version 5.7 is rated at about 64 *simultaneous queries* before the throughput stops improving, and (instead), response time heads for infinity.

To do realistic benchmarking, you need to provide realistic values for

- How often a query is issued.  (Benchmark programs tend to throw queries at the server one after another; this is not realistic.)
- How long a query takes.
- How many connections are involved.  (I claim that 100K is not realistic.)

The heavy-hitters deliver millions of web pages per day.  The typical page involves:  connect, do a few queries, build html, disconnect -- all (typically) in less than a second.  But only a small fraction of the time is any running.  That is, 100 connections may equate to 0-5 queries running at any instant.

Please talk about Queries per second that need to be run. And please limit the number of queries run *simultaneously*.

Comment: Thank you so much @Rick for such a explained knowledge . One thing that I understood from your answer is that there is something wrong in making connections. I am not using persistant connections. so everytime user is having new connection while calling my apis.I guess I need to google around it to use connection pooling